# Raspberry software protection

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, source-code-protection

I have a python script on raspberry pi 3 and I want to secure my script as much as possible. The user can only contact with the touch screen so there is no external hardware like keyboard, mouse etc. What should I take measure against stolen? For example disabling usb ports, encoding script...

Comment: If they have the hardware, they can simply take the memory card out of it and put it into their own device.

Comment: @UnholySheep it is medical monitoring software. If user can acce and can use the medical periphals unlimited. Medical periphals have some using limits. The most important thing is the user mustn't read the code.

Answer (score 0):

Everything a Raspberry Pi 3 "knows" is on that little micro-SD card.  The only way to gain some security is to **physically secure the device** in an enclosure that prevents the user from getting the SD card.  And you need to make your software hard to break into -- difficult for an interpreted language like python -- but made a lot easier if there's no keyboard or other ports available.  Again, protected inside the enclosure.  If the users can literally only get to the touch screen, then I have a hard time imagining how they'd steal your software.